# Probability in Set Notation

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory, notation

A coin is ﬂipped 10 times. Writing Heads as 1 and Tails as 0, the outcome is a sequence (s<sub>1</sub>,...,s<sub>10</sub>) with s<sub>j</sub> ∈ {0,1}, and the sample space S consists of the $2^{10}$ = 1024 such sequences. Let A<sub>j</sub> be the event that $s_j$ = 1. How can the events “at least one ﬂip was Heads”, “exactly one ﬂip was Heads”, “all the ﬂips were Heads”, and “there were two consecutive Heads” be written compactly in set notation?

I decided to self-study Probability and Statistics from the Harvard Stat110x course on youtube. I downloaded their handouts and practice sheets from the course website and came across this question in their math_review handout.

My answer:

At least one flip was heads: $\bigcup_{j=1}^{10}A_j$

Exactly one flip was heads: ???

All flips were heads: $\bigcap_{j=1}^{10}A_j$

Two consecutive heads: $\bigcup_{i=1}^9[\bigcap_{j=i}^{i+1}A_j]$

How do I write exactly one flip is head in compact set notation? Are my other answers correct? I would love to hear other alternatives to my answers.

Comment: Your first, third, and fourth are good, though I might have preferred to see $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^9 A_i\cap A_{i+1}$ instead for the last but that is just preference.  As for the second, perhaps $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{10}\left( A_i\cap \left(\bigcap\limits_{j=1\\j\neq i}^{10}A_j^c\right)\right)$.  It would have been cleaner had these been random variables instead of random events and we could have talked about $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{10}A_i = 1$ instead

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks. But, I didn't get the part about random variables. I'll go through this again after I have studied random variables.